# Flipping coins problem Find E(x) and Var(x)

Tags: expected-value, constraints

There is a fair coin and a biased coin that flips heads with probability 1/4. You randomly pick one of the coins and flip it until you get a heads. Let X be the number of flips you need. Compute E(X) and Var[X].

In the question, I did:

Let H denotes to get a head, $$P(H)= \frac12*\frac12+\frac12*\frac14=\frac38$$
$$E(X)=\frac1p=\frac83$$
$$Var(X)=\frac q{p^2} = \frac {40}9$$

but the TA said the answer is $$E(X)=3$$ $$Var(X)=8$$
I hava no clue where I did it wrong

Comment: You pick the fair or biased cone with probability ${1 \over 2}$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes

Comment: How does your computation relate to computing $E[X], \operatorname{var} X$??? $X$ is the number of times needs to get a head.

Comment: Try computing $E(X) = E(X | \text{fair})P(\text{fair}) + E(X | \text{biased})P(\text{biased})$.

Comment: Your answer would be valid if you were choosing a random coin for each toss instead of choosing a random coin and using that same coin for all tosses.

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of tosses to get a head if the probability of a head is $p$ is $E[X_p] = {1 \over p}$.

(This can be quickly checked from the equation
$p\cdot 1 + (1-p)\cdot (E[X_p] +1) = E[X_p]$ .)

Then if $C=1$ with probability ${ 1\over 2}$ if you choose the fair coin and $C=0$ with probability ${ 1\over 2}$ if you choose the biased coin the
outcome will be
$C\cdot X_{1 \over 2} + (1-C) \cdot X_{1 \over 4}$ and so
\begin{eqnarray}
E[C\cdot X_{1 \over 2} + (1-C) \cdot X_{1 \over 4}] &=& E[C\cdot] E[ X_{1 \over 2}] + E[1-C] \cdot E[X_{1 \over 4}] \\
&=& {1 \over 2} \cdot 2 + { 1\over 2} \cdot 4 \\
&=& 3
\end{eqnarray}